# Selenium fails to find class if browser is not open in windows

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium in python to extract data, if the browser is not open in windows, it throws the error below, but if I leave the browser open, everything works fine. The code ran for over 5 hours non-stop with the browser open.
Now I can't always leave the browser open since I have to do other things as well. Please find my code and the error shown below.

```
try:
            #interest by Geo data container
            geo_container = WebDriverWait(self.browser, random.randint(fixed_time,fixed_time*2)).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "widget[class='multi-heat-map-widget']")))
        
        except:
            geo_container = WebDriverWait(self.browser, random.randint(fixed_time,fixed_time*2)).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "widget[type='fe_geo_chart']")))

           
        #download data
        geo_download_button = WebDriverWait(geo_container, random.randint(fixed_time*2,fixed_time*4)).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".widget-actions-item.export")))
        geo_download_button.click()
```

[my code[geo_container and geo_cantainer class[download_button and class[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8yy3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa9Dv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQOXQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7ClK.png)

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `headless` option.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
```

Comment: I already added headless, this is what my  chrome option looks like options.add_argument('--headless=new')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
 options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', '127.0.0.1:9222')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)